# Is this a normal scenario for a job negotiation?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, seniority

A month or so ago,I applied for 2 positions in a company. One as Writer (which it was supposed to be remote) and one as Senior Editor (which payment was double of the offered as Writer since it was in a office with official hours).

After my first interview with Human Resources, I felt she didn’t like me, you know, not so much eye contact, short answers etc.

But only a day after I received an offer to join a second interview with a local team of editors. This time I was told they were considering me for the Writer position.

I decided to go on although I make myself clear I wanted the Senior position when I was asked in the first interview.

I joined this second interview but was funny that the team who interviewed me point it our during the chat -which was quite nice and long- that my profile was more close to the Senior role than the Writer. They said this more than 3 times.

After this interview I received an invitation to make a test, which was titled as “Senior Editor Test” and I was told by HR that I was now considered for both positions.

I send back the test and they told me to wait one week to get feedback, but just a couple of hours later they invited to a final interview with the CEO of all the projects markets of this content agency.

I attend the interview and during this one I was only asked about my background as Senior, managing people etc...the chat was long and by the second half of it , the interviewer started to say things as “when you work with us you will have meeting with x or y” “don’t worry if you have doubts you count on me and ....” “you will be in charge of 2 people”.

So I honestly felt I was having the job in my pocket. Mostly because since the beginning they portrayed this final interview as THE MOST IMPORTANT ONE.

Like in the previous steps of the process I receives compliments and also a lot of details about the position, details I think you will not bother to give to someone who will be not hired.

The thing is that, and sorry for the long story, some days ago I received and email offering a job, yes, but the WRITER ROLE ...haha.

They asked me to understand that they preferred someone with one year more experience than me.

Anyways, I rejected the offer explaining that I was feeling fooled because seemed that they wanted me for the Writer role the whole time and that it was a mistake that they implied me so much in the Senior role in the last interview -seemed the CEO was told I was the one to the get the Senior position so he was just welcoming me-.

I send my answer and now I’m surprised because I receive an apology and a new offer that includes being not Writer but SENIOR Writer (seems just a semantic move).

They told me I’m a very qualified person so they also add also a small increase in the payment (100 USD) but with a change in the role (and here is when I got again between confused and angry). The change implies help the Senior Editor in his duties and to review the text of the other junior writer they are looking for.

I was thinking , because they seemed into me o desperate to get someone, in answer the offer with a new negotiation, I mean, if they want me to be a kinda boss but without other attributions I should get at least more than half of the payment offer to the Senior Editor.

I think they might accept my offer. Or should I just declined the whole thing and let it go because they didn’t take me in first instance? I mean, seems they wanted a Senior in a junior Editor to make a strong team and of course put me to work ASAP because they haven’t get any other Writer.

Please, I would love to have some feedback, I have never face a situation like this. Sorry if my English is poor, but is not my mother tongue and I need to improve it. I'm writing from Chile, when I must said the jobs are bad paid and rare to find.

Comment: Hey Viviana. Your post is currently really hard to read. Please, try to reduce it and separate it into parragraphs. Also, asking "Should I take the job" is off-topic on this site, as it is asking us to make a choice for you.

Comment: Are you asking "if you should take the job" or "if you should be worried about taking the job because of..." the reasons you've listed above?

Comment: I'm afraid we can't tell you whether to take a job or not - you need to decide for yourself whether the job satisfaction, salary, general fit, location etc. make it worth your while. If not, or you can't get what you think you're worth, then walk away.

Comment: Adding on to what @DarkCygnus said, you can [read why advice on a specific choice](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change#2695) is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: As already mentioned, "Should I take the job?" is unfortunately off topic for this site. You might want to rephrase it to instead ask something along the lines of "Is X a red flag?", if possible. It would also help if you [edit] your question to focus on the most important points and try to cut it down to about half or a third of the length it is now. Plenty of people don't like reading through long posts, so making such an edit will help you get more and better responses, and it will make it less likely for people to miss some important details hidden in the post.

Comment: @Vivi It is best to use the same account as you used to write the question to apply any edits. I have approved your edit to change the focus from "Should I do x?" and removed the impolite comment. I also moved your comment you had written as an answer to be a comment here.

Comment: Great re-edit, what country is this in? That will also help give better insights.

Answer (score 4):

My advice to you is to **ignore any potential confusion of the past and instead look at the employment conditions offer**, and you should decide on this.

Hiring can be a messy business, and yes, often people will be considered for different roles. I think provided that they showed you respect, that's the most important thing when it comes to the process itself.

Just because the CEO used optimistic language doesn't mean you were a lock-in. Rather than prefix ever sentence with "If you were hired..." they just assume that is the fact.

Comment: I agree. Also, from what I read from the question, nobody seemed to be 'playing games' - they seriously considered the OP for the Senior Editor role but finally decided for someone else. I think their apology and the 'Senior Writer' position (which did not exist initially) is a serious and respectful offer, which one can take or decline.

Answer (score 0):

Until you have an offer, you don't have the job. I understand that when things go well, it's easy to think "This job is mine !", but something can always come up. Maybe you were great, but the next person they interviewed was even an even better fit. Maybe that person had an extra year of experience and that was made their decision. Maybe there's not another candidate, but they really want someone with more experience for this role and thought you would do better in a less senior role. Also, when someone in an interview says "You will be in charge of two people", they mean "The person in this position will be in charge of two people", not you specifically.

You did apply to the writer position, si it's not that weird that they would think you'd be interested by it. Nothing in your post raises a red flag for me. You applied to two positions, they interviewed you several times, they made you an offer for one of those. The fact that they were quick to offer you the senior writer role, with added responsibilities, tells me they did like you as a candidate, it's just that the senior editor role isn't the right fit for them.

If you were interested in the writer position, consider their offer. I'd ask them to have one more interview though, since in past interviews you've mainly talked about the senior editor one. Ask what are the difference between a writer and senior writer. Based on that information (additional responsibilities), you'll be able to make a better counteroffer. If you wish to have the senior editor role in the future, I would also reiterate my interest in that role and if there's a path for me to get there, etc...